# NodeJS POST request to API, document recieved but logs error URI too long

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, post

I am trying to make a POST request with NodeJS that returns a binary document. While it seems to go through and I am able to console.log the binary document from the data response chunks, if I try to pipe into a file or upload the body variable to S3 I just get a document with a 414 Error URI too large, from the same data chunks that logged the correct document.

I've inspected both the request and response and everything seems to be fine, no long URLs, no GET requests, so I'm struggling to find where the error is coming from. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
var req = {required json data}
var body = '';

function doPost(data) {
    // Build the post string from an object
    var post_data = JSON.stringify(data);

    // An object of options to indicate where to post to
    var post_options = {
        host: 'some.thing.com',
        port: '443',
        path: '/path/to/render',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(post_data)
        }
    };

    var file = fs.createWriteStream('result.doc');

    // Set up the request
    var post_req = https.request(post_options, function(res) {
        // console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
        // console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.pipe(file);

        res.on('data', function(chunk)  {
            console.log('data response:' + chunk);
            body += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', function() {
            console.log('response inspect: ' + util.inspect(res));
        });
    });

    // post the data
    post_req.write(post_data);
    post_req.end();
    console.log('REQUEST INSPECT:' + util.inspect(post_req));
}

if(req) {
    doPost(req);
}
```

Comment: Based on your explanation it would look like error is coming from your server sending it to S3, is that correct?

Comment: Nope because at this point I removed all AWS services from the function, and am calling it from the command line. It turns out that res.setEncoding was the culprit, and I was able to render the document locally. Now I'm back to testing it in Lambda where I didn't have the setEncoding to begin with

Comment: possible duplicate of [AWS Lambda - NodeJS POST request and asynch write/read file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32636956/aws-lambda-nodejs-post-request-and-asynch-write-read-file)

Comment: You should ask about your code in one place.

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32636956/aws-lambda-nodejs-post-request-and-asynch-write-read-file