# can use API GET but not API POST

Tags: c#, node.js, post, get, aws-lambda

Im working on an existing Windows Service project in VS 2013.

I've added a web API Controller class I cant remember now if its a (v2.1) or (v1) controller class....Anyway I've called it SyncPersonnelViaAwsApiController

Im trying to call it from a AWS lambda...so If I call the GET

```
public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
```

with const req = https.request('https://actualUrlAddress/api/SyncPersonnelViaAwsApi/Get/4', (res) => {

I get `returned body: undefined"value"` which is correct.
 However if I try and call

```
const req = https.request('https://actualUrlAddress/api/SyncPersonnelViaAwsApi/SapCall', (res) => {
```

I get `returned body: undefined{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."}`

```
 //// POST api/<controller>
    public string SapCall([FromBody]string xmlFile)
    {
        string responseMsg = "Failed Import User";

        if (!IsNewestVersionOfXMLFile(xmlFile))
        {
            responseMsg = "Not latest version of file, update not performed";
        }
        else
        {
            Business.PersonnelReplicate personnelReplicate = BusinessLogic.SynchronisePersonnel.BuildFromDataContractXml<Business.PersonnelReplicate>(xmlFile);
            bool result = Service.Personnel.SynchroniseCache(personnelReplicate);

            if (result)
            {
                responseMsg = "Success Import Sap Cache User";
            }
        }

        return "{\"response\" : \" " + responseMsg + " \" , \"isNewActiveDirectoryUser\" : \" false \"}";
    }
```

Does anyone have any idea why it works for GET and not POST?

As we can hit the get im confident its not the lambda but I have included it just incase

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const https = require('https');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
var un;
var pw;
var seralizedXmlFile;


let index = function index(event, context, callback) {

    // For the purpose of testing I have populated the bucket and key params with objects that already exist in the S3 bucket  
    var params = {
    Bucket: "testbucketthur7thdec",
    Key: "personnelData_50312474_636403151354943757.xml"
};


// Get Object from S3 bucket and add to 'seralizedXmlFile'
s3.getObject(params, function (data, err) {
    console.log("get object from S3 bucket");
    if (err) {
        // an error occurred
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("data " + data);
        // populate seralizedXmlFile with data from S3 bucket
        let seralizedXmlFile = err.Body.toString('utf-8'); // Use the encoding necessary
        console.log("objectData " + seralizedXmlFile);
    }

});

    // set params
    var ssm = new AWS.SSM({ region: 'Usa2' });
    console.log('Instatiated SSM');
    var paramsx = {
        'Names': ['/Sap/ServiceUsername', '/Sap/ServicePassword'],
        'WithDecryption': true
    };

// password and username
    ssm.getParameters(paramsx, function (err, data) {
        console.log('Getting parameter');
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else {
            console.log('data: ' + JSON.stringify(data));           // successful response
            console.log('password: ' + data.Parameters[0].Value);
            console.log('username: ' + data.Parameters[1].Value);
            pw = data.Parameters[0].Value;
            un = data.Parameters[1].Value;
        }


        // request to external api application & remove dependency on ssl
        process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";

        //POST DOES NOT WORK
        const req = https.request('https://actualUrlAddress/api/SyncPersonnelViaAwsApi/SapEaiCall', (res) => {
        //GET WORKS
       // const req = https.request('https://actualUrlAddress/api/SyncPersonnelViaAwsApi/Get/4', (res) => {

            res.headers + 'Authorization: Basic ' + un + ':' + pw;
            let body = seralizedXmlFile;
            console.log('seralizedXmlFile: ' + seralizedXmlFile); 
            console.log('Status:', res.statusCode);
            console.log('Headers:', JSON.stringify(res.headers));

            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            res.on('data', (chunk) => body += chunk);
            res.on('end', () => {
                console.log('Successfully processed HTTPS response');
                callback(null, body);
                console.log('returned body:', body);

            });
        });
        req.end();
    });
};
exports.handler = index;
```

**UPDATE**
Thanks to @Thangadurai post with [AWS Lambda - NodeJS POST request and asynch write/read file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32636956/aws-lambda-nodejs-post-request-and-asynch-write-read-file)

I was able to include a post_options...please see updated lambda

```
          // An object of options to indicate where to post to
    var post_options = {
        host: 'https://actualUrlAddress',
        port: '80',
        path: '/api/SyncPersonnelViaAwsApi/SapEaiCall',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Length': post_data.length
        }
    };

 const req = https.request(post_options, (res) => {
   res.headers + 'Authorization: Basic ' + un + ':' + pw;
            let body = seralizedXmlFile;
            console.log('seralizedXmlFile: ' + seralizedXmlFile); 
            console.log('Status:', res.statusCode);
            console.log('Headers:', JSON.stringify(res.headers));

            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            res.on('data', (chunk) => body += chunk);
            res.on('end', () => {
                console.log('Successfully processed HTTPS response');
                callback(null, body);
                console.log('returned body:', body);

            });
        });
        req.end();
```

It is now flagging as error:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http://actualUrlAddress http://actualUrlAddress.private:80
```

I had this getaggrinfo ENOTFOUND error before, it means it cant find the address....but arnt the hostname and api path correct?

I am trying to reach

```
const req = https.request('https://actualUrlAddress/api/SyncPersonnelViaAwsApi/SapCall
```

and yes the port is 80

any help would be appreciated
Ta
M

Comment: The error says that `/GET` is unsupported, not that `/POST` is unsupported.

Comment: From your description and code, GET works because the API method `https://actualUrlAddress/api/SyncPersonnelViaAwsApi/Get/4` is designed to accept HTTP GET request. But the other API method `SapCall` supports only HTTP POST verb, I am assuming this because a comment in the API method definition says so, and the [FromBody] attribute also indicates that. [Note: HTTP GET request will not have a body.

Comment: @AluanHaddad thank yo for reply, I know what the error says but that is the rror I see when I try to call POST

Comment: @Thangadurai thank you for reply, what are you suggesting that the body is empty?

Comment: @John I think you aren't sending a post request.

Comment: @AluanHaddad ok that may make sense do you know what I am doing wrong in my lambda then to change it to a post?

Comment: No, but I suspect you need to make tell the API to make a post request, it cannot infer that

Comment: http.request takes an options parameter where you can specify the http method and other details. You need to prepare your request as described in [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32636956/aws-lambda-nodejs-post-request-and-asynch-write-read-file) post

Comment: @Thangadurai thank you for your reply it has helped but still stuck. If you would please look at UPDATE part of OP thank you

Comment: Just read documentation of what you are using: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback. Host should be `actualUrlAddress`, not `https://actualUrlAddress`. If you want to use "https" - set that as `protocol: 'https'` in `post_options`. Also remove port, it's 80 by default (and when you set protocol `https` - it will be just wrong, since https endpoint should be on 443 port).

Comment: @Evk thank you for your help. Much appreciated. If you would like to write this as an answer I will award you the points

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Skipping right to the update part (everything else is not relevant as I understand). Options should look like this:

```
var post_options = {
    host: 'actualUrlAddress',
    protocol: 'https:'
    port: '443',
    path: '/api/SyncPersonnelViaAwsApi/SapEaiCall',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': post_data.length
    }
};
```

Since as [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) states, host and protocol are in two separate properties, and SSL port is very unlikely to be 80, usually it is 443.

Comment: thanks again for your help. If you have the time maybe you could take a quick look at the follow up https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49788577/aws-lambda-call-not-populating-body-on-post

Answer (score 4):

Given that Web API is being used the assumption is that the default routeing has also been configured.

I would suggest enabling attribute routing

Reference [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

```
public static class WebApiConfig {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
        // Attribute routing.
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Convention-based routing.
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

and updating the controller with the appropriate attributes and syntax

```
[RoutePrefix("api/SyncPersonnelViaAwsApi")]
public class SyncPersonnelViaAwsApiController : ApiController {

    //GET api/SyncPersonnelViaAwsApi/4
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:int}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int id) {
        return Ok("value");
    }

    //POST api/SyncPersonnelViaAwsApi
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult SapCall([FromBody]string xmlFile) {
        string responseMsg = "Failed Import User";

        if (!IsNewestVersionOfXMLFile(xmlFile)) {
            responseMsg = "Not latest version of file, update not performed";
        } else {
            Business.PersonnelReplicate personnelReplicate = BusinessLogic.SynchronisePersonnel.BuildFromDataContractXml<Business.PersonnelReplicate>(xmlFile);
            bool result = Service.Personnel.SynchroniseCache(personnelReplicate);
            if (result) {
                responseMsg = "Success Import Sap Cache User";
            }
        }

        var data = new { 
            response = responseMsg,
            isNewActiveDirectoryUser = false
        };

        Ok(data);
    }
}
```

Take note of the expected paths in the comments above the actions.

The `[Http{Verb}]` attributes tell the routing framework what requests can be mapped to the action.

now from the client the paths to call would be

```
GET api/SyncPersonnelViaAwsApi/4
POST api/SyncPersonnelViaAwsApi
```

As already mentioned in the comments, the port 80 is not used for HTTP calls. Even the linked example in the updated question uses port `443` for HTTPS calls. The header in options show JSON yet the `body` infers that XML is being sent.

```
var post_options = {
    host: 'actualUrlAddress',
    protocol: 'https',
    port: '443',
    path: '/api/SyncPersonnelViaAwsApi',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
        'Content-Length': post_data.length
    }
};
```

In order for the client to successfully communicate with the Web API the client will need to make sure it is making a valid request.